# How to loop through JSON Data?

Tags: asp.net, jquery, json, json.net

I have an ashx page that returns the following JSON data that I would like to be able to loop through and add to values to a bunch of li's in a ul.

My question is how do I loop through to retrieve the values.

The data that is returned from the ashx look slike this

```
{"ImageCollection":
    {
        "Images":
            [
                {
                    "ImageID":"62",
                    "CatID":"1",
                    "Location":"/Images/62.gif",
                    "FullHeight":"466","FullWidth":"606"
                },
                {
                    "ImageID":"63",
                    "CatID":"1",
                    "Location":"/Images/63.gif",
                    "FullHeight":"205",
                    "FullWidth":"751"
                }
            ]
    }
}
```

and if I try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.getJSON("/Service/GetJson.ashx?data=images", function(data) {
        var jsObjectData = eval(data);
        $.each(data, function(i, item) {
            alert(data[i].ImageID);
        });
    });
</script>
```

I get a single alert that says undefined. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no need to eval in this case, you can just do this:

```
$.getJSON("/Service/GetJson.ashx?data=images", function(data) {
    var jsObjectData = data.ImageCollection.Images;
    $.each(jsObjectData, function(i, item) {
        alert(item.ImageID);
    });
});
```

[`$.getJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) already converts it to an object, so just treat it like that, `data` is the overall object, and inside you want to loop though the `ImageCollection.Images`, so pass that to your [`$.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) call.